# Match words following ignore words containing characters

Tags: regex, powershell

I'm looking to match everything past the final - but ignoring words that contain `()`.

Example:

> Tablet-MS Surface Pro 4 - Ricardo Cortez (OFFSITE)

How can I get just `Ricardo Cortez` ?

This is what I tried:

```
/[^-]+(?![(][)])+$/g
```

Thank You

Comment: What tool or programming language are you using?

Comment: I am just trying to get the regex right and then I want to do it inside a power shell script that reads the description from active directory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might use an [alternation](https://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html) to first match what you don't want and capture in a group what you do want.

This pattern does not require that the hyphen is in the string based on your pattern where you are using a negated character class `[^-]+` to not match a hyphen but actually are not matching it as a required character.

```
^.*-|(?:^|[ \t]+)([^\s()]+)(?!\S)
```

**Explanation**

- `^` Start of string
- `.*-` Match any char 0+ times and then `-` so it will match the last hyphen
- `|` Or
- `(?:^|[ \t]+)` Assert the start of the string or match 1+ times a space or tab
- `([^\s()]+)` Capture in group 1 matching `+ times not a whitespace char or`(`or`)`
- `(?!\S)` Negative lookahead, assert what is on the right is not a non whitespace char

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/HKGy98/1)

**Edit**

If you want to use replace you could match all that you don't want to keep and replace with an empty string:

```
^.*-\s*|\s*\S*[()]+\S*
```

**Explanation**

- `^.*-\s*` Match any char unit the last hyphen followed by 0+ whitespace chars
- `|` Or
- `\s*` Match 0+ times a whitespace
- `\S*[()]+\S*` Match 0+ times a non whitespace char, match not `(` or `)` 1+ times and again 0+ times a non whitespace char

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/40DpNz/1/)

For example

```
$string = "Tablet - MS Surface Pro 4 - Ricardo Cortez (OFFSITE)"
$name = $string -replace '^.*-|\S*[()]+\S*','' 
echo $name
```

Comment: This is working well in the regex demo but I tried this in PowerShell and it didn't quite work:

Comment: $string = "Tablet - MS Surface Pro 4 - Ricardo Cortez (OFFSITE)"
$name = $string -replace '/^.*-|(?:^|[ \t]+)([^\s()]+)(?!\S)','$1'
$name
Tablet-MSSurfacePro4-RicardoCortez (OFFSITE)

Comment: It looks like I'm getting a space before R. Thanks for your help I'm not the best with programming and this helps me learn

Comment: Do you mean the R in the example string?

Answer (score 0):

Not knowing how you are running this regular expression, I would suggest something along the lines of this:

```
/ - ([^\(]+) /g
```

which aims to capture everything within the parenthesis. Basically, find a match that begins with the hyphen, then capture everything until it hits an opening parenthesis character (i.e. any character that is not an open parenthesis).

Comment: That works to exclude words in parenthesis. I'm trying to clean up our inventory list. With / - ([^\(]+) /g I get the space preceding the - as well as the - and the space following dash. How can I just get Ricardo Cortez with the only space being between the words? In some instances we have spaces between - sometimes just the -. Is it possible? Thanks

Comment: You're going to have to tell us what language you are using and what command/tool. Then, tag the question with the appropriate information so someone familiar with that language/command/tool can answer your question. With some tools, you can match only the parenthesis with the regex I posted in my answers, which would exclude the spaces before and after Ricardo Cortez.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you want to remove the name. If so, we want to capture it then replace it using capturing groups. Maybe, an expression similar to:

```
(.+?-\s)([A-Z].+)(\(.+)
```

[image]

### [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/N6pMWr/1/)

```js
const regex = /(.+?-\s)([A-Z].+)(\(.+)/gm;
const str = `Tablet-MS Surface Pro 4 - Ricardo Cortez (OFFSITE)`;
const subst = `$1$3`;

// The substituted value will be contained in the result variable
const result = str.replace(regex, subst);

console.log('Substitution result: ', result);
```

If we might want to remove `()` and everything in it, we can swipe every chars in the first capturing group, then capture the undesired, then replace with the `$1`:

```
([\s\S].*?)(\(.+?\))?
```

```js
const regex = /([\s\S].*?)(\(.+?\))?/gm;
const str = `Tablet-MS Surface Pro 4 - Ricardo Cortez (OFFSITE)Tablet-MS Surface Pro 4 - Ricardo Cortez (OFFSITE)Tablet-MS Surface Pro 4 - Ricardo Cortez (OFFSITE)Tablet-MS Surface Pro 4 - Ricardo Cortez (OFFSITE)Tablet-MS Surface Pro 4 - Ricardo Cortez`;
const subst = `$1`;

// The substituted value will be contained in the result variable
const result = str.replace(regex, subst);

console.log('Substitution result: ', result);
```

### [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/ftBWj9/1/)

[image]

#### RegEx Circuit

[jex.im](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5E(a%7Cb)*%3F%24) also helps to visualize the expressions.

[image]